# Crear carpeta con PHP y verificar si ya existe

Tags: php, html, archivo

Tengo un archivo "crearcarpeta.php" que al ejecutarlo desde un `form` externo crea una carpeta, pero no he podido hacer que verifique si ya está creada.

Este es el archivo "crearcarpeta.php":

```
<?php 

    $nombre = ($_POST['nombre']);

    if(!is_dir($_POST['nombre'])){ 
        @mkdir($_POST['nombre'], 0700); 
    }else{ 
        echo "Ya existe ese directorio\n"; 
    }  
    header("Location: crearpanel.php?nombre=$nombre");
?>
```

El problema está en que, cuando ingreso el nombre de una carpeta que ya existe, la crea nuevamente reemplazando la existente, necesito que no la reemplace sino que diga "Ya existe ese directorio" pero no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: el contenido de `$_POST['nombre']` es solo un `string` por lo que buscara en la ruta donde se este llamando el `archivo` lo mejor es agregar una ruta `absoluta` y no `relativa` ejemplo `if(!is_dir("/var/www/html/proyecto/carpetas/".$_POST['nombre']))` tambien puedes incluirle `is_readable()` para validar que exista y sea legible!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar la página de PHP cuando tengas este tipo de dudas:

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> **[file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)** — Comprueba si existe un fichero o directorio

```
file_exists ( string $filename ) : bool
```

> Devuelve **TRUE** si el fichero o directorio especificado por filename existe; **FALSE** si no.

Comment: Amigo he intentado de muchas forams y no hago que funcione cuando el archivo.php es externo, como tiene un header location automaticamente me lleva a la pagina que he colocado y no funciona ya que todo se reemplaza igual.. me podrias ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa, ¿Por qué estás usando el $_POST en todo si lo estas guardando en la variable $nombre ?

```
<?php 

    $nombre = ($_POST['nombre']);

    if(!is_dir($_POST['nombre'])){ 
        @mkdir($_POST['nombre'], 0700); 
    }else{ 
        echo "Ya existe ese directorio\n"; 
    }  
    header("Location: crearpanel.php?nombre=$nombre");
?>
```

En vez de

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

if(!is_dir($nombre)){

 @mkdir($nombre, 0700); 
}else{ 
 echo "Ya existe ese directorio\n";
}

header("Location: crearpanel.php?nombre=$nombre");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aplica `is_dir` a tu ruta relativa

Ejemplo:
url: http://loquesea.com
carpeta: public/extra/nuevacarpeta
ruta absoluta: http://loquesea.com/extra/nuevacarpeta
ruta relativa: extra/nuevacarpeta

```
if (is_dir('extra/nuevacarpeta')){
//continua con tus operaciones
}
else {
//crea carpeta y continua con tus operaciones
}
```